# list index out of range inside for loop at index 2

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

So I have been running into a really weird error. I have a module ten.py containing

```
import math

def go():
    list_ = list(range(3, 100000, 2))
    max_ = int(math.sqrt(len(list_)))
    print(len(list_))
    print(max_)
    for i in range(1,max_):
        print(i)
        current = list_[i]
        for j in list_[i+1:]:
            if j % i == 0:
                list_.remove(j)
go()
```

The output is this:

```
49999
223
1
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents\KomodoProjects\Project Euler\ten.py", line 14, in <module>
    go()
  File "D:\Documents\KomodoProjects\Project Euler\ten.py", line 10, in go
    current = list_[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

As you can see the size of list is 49999 and the for loop only goes to 223. Despite all this it already gives an index out of range exception at index=2!

Is the list_ inside the for loop somehow not referencing to the list_ inside go()? I have no clue as to why this problem occurs.

Fixed by changing

```
for i in range(1,max_):
```

to
    for i in list_:

Comment: The traceback mentions a variable `current` yet this variable does not appear in your given code.  Maybe you should post the actual code you are running.

Comment: Oh sorry I removed that line but Didn't update the traceback. Editing now.

Comment: Also - for Euler in general - you may find this post of interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python

Comment: Thanks, I think I skimmed over that one earlier but for now I am more curious as to why this specific error occurs.

Comment: Hint: `i` is 1 to start with, right?  Which numbers are congruent to 0 mod 1, and will therefore be deleted if you loop over them?

Comment: Thanks the answer helped me fixed it. list_ = list(range(3, 2000000, 2)) takes forever though, which is what I want to do for the Euler problem. Any idea why? Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your problem:

You have a `for` loop that is deleting numbers from `list_`.  It is deleting so many numbers that `list_` is length 2, and then `list_[2]` fails and raises an exception.

The reason it is deleting so many numbers is that you are computing `x % 1 == 0` which is true for any value of x.  Since you start at position 2 in the list, you are deleting everything after that position.

I'm not certain exactly what you are doing but this is going to be a slow way to do it, whatever it is.  This looks sort of like screening for prime numbers... you might want to do a Google search for "Python find prime numbers" or something.

Comment: Particularly, at `i=1`, *any* value of `j` will return `true` for `j%i==0` (1 divides evenly into everything).

Comment: Oh wow somehow the outer for loop started at 1. It was supposed to not even be a range() but just list_. That must have gotten messed up somehow while I was testing different things.